# Prove that $L=\left\{ab^{k_1}ab^{k_2}...ab^{k_n}c^m|\forall i:k_i>0\text{ and } m>n>0\right\}$ is not regular using Pumping Lemma

Tags: regular-language, pumping-lemma

Prove that $L=\left\{ab^{k_1}ab^{k_2}...ab^{k_n}c^m|\forall i:k_i>0\text{ and } m>n>0\right\}$ is not regular using Pumping Lemma.

So here is my reasoning:

1. Assume that $L \in Reg$ ($Reg$ is the set of regular languages)
2. Since regular languages are closed under complement and intersection of sets, define $L'$ as $L'=\bar{L} \cap c^*(ab^*)^*$ where $L'=\left\{c^mab^{k_1}ab^{k_2}...ab^{k_n}|\exists i:k_i=0\text{ or } m\le n\text{ or }n = 0\right\}$
3. Prove that $L'$ is not regular using the Pumping Lemma, if $L'$ is not regular then $\bar{L}$ is not regular and so $L$ is not regular.

So here are my questions:

- is step 2 legal? can I do $L'=\bar{L} \cap c^*(ab^*)^*$ to prove that $L$ is not regular?
- is the conditions of $L'=\left\{c^mab^{k_1}ab^{k_2}...ab^{k_n}|\exists i:k_i=0\text{ or } m\le n\text{ or }n = 0\right\}$ correct (after doing the complement operation on  $\left\{\forall i:k_i>0\text{ and } m>n>0\right\}$ )?
- Is my approach is the right approach for such question?

Notes:

- I purposely avoided adding the part where I use the Pumping Lemma on $L'$ since the part I'm finding difficulty in is the above.
- I think (not sure) that this question can be solved without using Demorgan's laws, but the result may not be as elegant.

Comment: OT: Why not use pumping lemma directly on $L$? It sis quite straightforward

Comment: I suppose you mean $\bar L\cap c^*(ab^*)^*$? Anyway, I am certain that $cab\in L'$, but it doesn't match your description.

Comment: I did but the solution did not turn to be as elegant as the above

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen can you explain more? what doesn't match the description?

Comment: Given that you are confused/have to ask about the structure of $L'$, I doubt that this will turn out as more elegant than "Let $p$ be the pumping length. Then $(ab)^pc^{p+1}\in L$can be written as $uvw$ with $|uv|\le p$ and such that $uv^rw\in L$ for all $r\ge 0$. In particular, $uv^{p+1}w\in L$. Clearly, $v$ cannot contain $c$. If $v$ contains at least one $a$, then $uvw$ contains at least $p+1$ times $a$, hence $n\ge p+1\ge m$, contradiction. It follows that $v=b$ and then $r=0$ gives us a word $\notin L$."

Comment: With "it doesn't match the description" I meant that "$\exists i\colon k_i=0\lor m\le n\lor n=0$" does not hold. Also, I meant to use $ccab$ instead of $cab$, sorry

Comment: Indeed your solution turned out to be more elegant from what I hoped to accomplish with $L'$.

Comment: If you can point out how I would 'fix' $L'$ that would help me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a shorter approach. Let $L' = L \cap (ab)^+c^+$. Observe that
$$
  L_1 = L \cap (ab)^+c^+ = \{(ab)^nc^m \mid m > n > 0\}
$$
Let $f: \{a,b\}^* \to \{a,b,c\}^*$ be the monoid morphism defined by $f(a) = ab$ and $f(b)=c$ and let $L_2 = f^{-1}(L_1)$. Then 
$$L_2 = \{a^nb^m \mid m > n > 0\}$$
Now, you probably already know that $L_2$ is not regular (otherwise, use the pumping lemma to prove it). Since regular languages are closed under intersection and under inverses of morphisms, $L$ is necessarily nonregular. Otherwise, $L_1$ and $L_2$ would be regular, a contradiction.